# Comparing Two Lists after Parse from a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have created a function that will parse through files in a directory and save the values in a list. I then run the function on three different directories. Once I do this I then want to compare the lists to see if they are equal. However, the function to do this is always returning False even when I copy and paste the same files in each directory. Below are the two functions I am working with.

**ParseFiles Function**:

```
def ParseFiles(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        # check filename to ensure it ends in appropriate file extension
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', 'confg')):
            # concatinate os path and filename
            file_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    # match everything after hostname
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    #store match in a list for use later
                    if match:
                        hostname = [match.group(1)]
                        return hostname
                        #print (hostname)
```

**Compare Parse**:

```
def ParseCompare(L1, L2):
    if len(L1) != len(L2):
        return False
    for val in L1:
        if val in L2:
            return False   
    return True
```

**Testing Parse**:

```
archiveParse = ParseFiles(TEST_PATH)
startupParse = ParseFiles(TEST_PATH_1)
runningParse = ParseFiles(TEST_PATH_2)

print ParseCompare(startupParse, archiveParse)

if ParseCompare(startupParse, archiveParse) == False:
    print("Startup does not match Archive")
if ParseCompare(startupParse, runningParse) == False:
    print("Startup and Running do not match")
if ParseCompare(runningParse, archiveParse) == False:
    print("Running does not match Archive")
else:
    print("Compared OK")
```

Comment: `for val in L1: if val in L2: return False`. So if you present two lists and they have an item in common, the function should return `False`?

Comment: so your function returns `None` or a 1-item list. Is that intentional?

Comment: I want it to return False if the lists do not match. True otherwise. If it's True i don't want to do anything with it. If it's False i will do other things.

Comment: Any Idea why the Parsefiles function is only returning the first file in the directory? When i print (hostname) is does everyone, but when i save it in a variable it only does the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Since your first check is that the lists are the same length, you avoid the issue with comparing list `d` here.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 2, 1]
c = [4, 2, 3]
d = [3, 3, 2, 1]

# Long version
def compare(L1, L2):
    """
    Create a list of booleans for every item, and only return True
    if *all* items in L1 are in L2
    """
    print("comparison lists are {} and {}".format(L1, L2))
    print("Boolean list is {}".format([item in L1 for item in L2]))

    if all(item in L1 for item in L2):
        print('Equal lists')
        return True

    print ('Not equal')
    return False

call1 = compare(a, b)
print "Bool value is: {}".format(call1)
print "..............."

call2 = compare(c, a)
print "Bool value is: {}".format(call2)
print "..............."

call3 = compare(a, d)
print "Bool value is: {}".format(call3)
print "..............."


# Short function
def compare(L1, L2):
    return all(item in L1 for item in L2)
```

Comment: I think i found the issue while debugging using your example. The ParseFile function for some reason is only returning the first parsed file in the directory and is not storing the rest. I'm not sure why this is happening.